# How to prematurely finish a pipeline within a JS transform

Tags: javascript, stream, transform, pipeline

Problem: I am dealing with large files (>10GB).
Sometimes I want to process the complete files and sometimes I just want to sample a few lines.

The processing setup is a pipeline:

```
        pipeline(
            inStream,
            split2(),
            sc,
            err => {
                 ...
            }
        );
```

`sc` is a transform that essentially counts some flags in the file.

The code works fine when processing the complete file but never produces the output in ... if I want to exit from the transform before `inStream` has finished.

```
        _transform(chunk,encoding,done) {
        let strChunk = decoder.write(chunk);
        if(strChunk === '\u0003') {
            this.push('\u0003');
            process.exit(0);
        }
        if(strChunk.startsWith("@")) {
            done();
        } else {
            if(this.sampleMax === 0) {
                this.push('\u0003');
                //process.exit(0);
            } else 
                if(this.sampleMax > 0)
                    this.sampleMax--;
            let dta = strChunk.split("\t");
            let flag = dta[1].trim();
            this.flagCount[flag]++;
            done();
        }
```

if I use `//process.exit(0)`, the code in the pipeline following `sc` is not reached.
if I only use `this.push('\u0003');` the complete inStream is processed.

The question is how to properly terminate the transform and continue with the downstream pipeline without completely reading `inStream`.

Comment: I found two options now. 1) throw an error when reaching the limit and checking for that error in the pipeline. 2) calling this.destroy() when reaching the limit and checking for the associated error (Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close) in the err part of the pipeline. Both options work, but I am hoping there is some better solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to throw an error or create an error implicitly by destroying the stream. Both options are shown in the code below.

```
_transform(chunk,encoding,done) {
    let strChunk = decoder.write(chunk);
    if(strChunk === '\u0003') {
        this.push('\u0003');
        process.exit(0);
    }
    if(strChunk.startsWith("@")) {
        done();
    } else {
        if(this.sampleMax === 0) {
            //Either of the following lines can solve the problem.
            throw("PLANNED_PREMATURE_TERMINATION");
            this.destroy(); //=> Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
        } else 
            if(this.sampleMax > 0)
                this.sampleMax--;
        let dta = strChunk.split("\t");
        let flag = dta[1].trim();
        this.flagCount[flag]++;
        done();
    }
```

The next step is to react to the errors generated in the above code in the pipeline.

```
    pipeline(
        inStream,
        split2(),
        sc,
        err => {
             if(err && (err === "PLANNED_PREMATURE_TERMINATION") || 
               (err === "Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close") {
                 //do whatever should happen in this case
             } else {
                //stream was completely processed
                //do whatever should happen in this case
             }
        }
    );
```

Since `err` contains the message that was thrown during premature termination, we can react to that specifically and present the partially aggregated data in `sc`. This solved the initial problem and seems to be the only obvious route in this situation. Therefore, I post this solution. Would be great to have other (more elegant) solutions.